# Get the color of the image using java

Tags: java

How to get the color of the image `icon.png` using java

Actually I have a servlet for that i wll be sending image using multipart file transfer,
now the server should respond back the color of the icon file, 
Here the image file has a single color;

Comment: What do you mean by "single color" of an image file? Unless it's a one-pixel image, there's multiple colors.

Comment: @Vulcan single color means all pixels are of same color.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the path to the image file:

```
Color getImageColor(File imagePath) {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imagePath);
    int color = image.getRGB(0, 0);
    for (int r = 0; r < image.getHeight(); r += 1) {
        for (int c = 0; c < image.getWidth(); c += 1) {
            if (image.getRGB(c, r) != color) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Image: " + imagePath + " is not a solid color.");
            }
        }
    }

    return new Color(color);
}
```

This code assumes that the image really does only have a single color and pulls the first pixel only.

The loop is there to make sure the entire image is one color. There are many ways to handle that situation, of course.

Comment: +1, but why extract the RGB to reconstruct the color, when you can simply do `return new Color(image.getRGB(0, 0))`?

Comment: @ShamsUdDin  One option is to loop over the image and throw an exception if the image is not a solid color. I've added some code to do that check. Other options are to average the colors, or to keep track of the most common colors and pick the most used one.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the BufferedImage (two loops - one from 0 to width, and one from 0 to height), and get the call getRgb(x, y). Then count each different value. You can use a Map for that (key = color, value = number of occurences). Note that this will give you counts of how often each color occurs in the image.